# Hard Drive Fails to Start Windows 10 - Is It Possible to Recover Data?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive-recovery

A family member's hard drive with Windows 10 Home on it is failing to boot up after a restart.  The Windows logo displays but after an hour nothing else.

I brought it home to see if I could recover data off of it on my Windows 10 Home machine.  The BIOS recognizes the drive fine and if I set it to be the boot drive I get the same result.  When I boot my machine with my normal drive set as the boot drive, Windows doesn't recognize the drive even after I rescan drives in Computer Mangement.

Is there a way to get the drive recognized so that I can recover data or is it totally dead?

Comment: Best thing now is to contact a local recovery agency.  There are tools like GetDataBack (https://www.runtime.org/) that you can try but a local agency will have more tools for this.

Comment: Are you able to access it when looting from a Linux LiveUSB? https://www.fosslinux.com/1532/create-a-boot-repair-live-usb-disk-drive-in-ubuntu-linux-mint-and-elementary-os.htm

Comment: @John I was thinking that may be the case.  Was just hoping to do it myself.

Comment: @K7AAY That's probably beyond my capabilities.

Comment: also see https://www.thewindowsclub.com/recover-windows-files-with-linux-live-cd-usb

Comment: Remove the drive and connect to another PC either usb or as a secondary drive, see if Windows can mount the drive, if it does, copy your files off

Comment: Would you please post screenshots of drives in device manager, disk management and [CrystalDiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/)?

Comment: Does Windows sees anything in the Computer Management? If it sees HDD but not drive you could try adding a letter to it, e.g E,F,G...

Answer (score 1):

Since it at least *starts* to boot, showing the Windows logo, likely the data *can* be saved. The easiest and safest way to do that requires mounting the drive *read-only* after booting from other media. As K7AAY states, a simple way would be to create a bootable USB drive and install Linux or Windows PE.

Since you're uncomfortable with Linux (which is actually the better choice), here's how to create a Windows PE disk on Windows:

1. Download [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree). (This is also a useful tool to backup and image a disk drive, to avoid the need to attempt to salvage a bad drive.)
2. Create a bootable rescue USB or CD [following their directions](https://kb.macrium.com/knowledgebasearticle50210.aspx).
3. Put the questionable drive back in the PC.
4. Boot that PC *from the rescue media*, following the instructions for that PC. Some PC's require holding down <kbd>F9</kbd> to select the boot device, some require changing BIOS settings after holding <kbd>F2</kbd>, etc.
5. Use the WinPE Explorer to open and browse the original HDD.
6. If you can see the file system, save any salvageable data to another USB device.
7. Once you're satisfied you've saved all you can, download the Windows 10 ISO and make a bootable Windows 10 USB using the [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).
8. Use the USB to either attempt to repair Windows, saving current files, or to completely reinstall Windows, losing data on the HDD.

If you're uncomfortable doing this, take the PC to a professional repair shop, and get a quote.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer but I think taking it to a repair shop is my best bet.